# Editing a predefined polygon using MapboxDraw library

Tags: mapbox, react-map-gl

Using @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw with React Map GL.

I can draw a polygon and save it to the DB. Now I need to edit an existing polygon coming from an api within the context of MapboxDraw.

I'm displaying polygons coming from the api as a source layer on the map. When a user clicks on a polygon i get the geometry and want to feed that geometry back into the MapboxDraw tool so it can be edited and updated via an  internal api.

I can add the polygon using the `draw.add` method but i can't trigger it outside of an event `map.on('load', ...)` or `map.on('click...')`.

To satisfy the design, the transition to polygon edit mode happens when a user click a button which is outside the context of the map within a side panel `(UIOverlay component)`.

Here is my code, I'm hard coding the geometry for now to get this working. Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

```
export const DrawPolygon = ({ mapMode, handleMapMode }: any) => {
  const [features, setFeatures] = useState({});
  const [plotToEdit, setPlotToEdit] = useState<Plot>();
  let draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    defaultMode: mapMode,
  });

  const onDrawPlot = useCallback((e: any) => {
    setFeatures(e.features[0]);
  }, []);

  const onDeletePlot = useCallback(() => {
    setFeatures({});
    handleMapMode('draw_polygon');
    draw.trash();
  }, []);

  const handlePlotToEdit = (plot: Plot) => {
    setFeatures(plot.geometry);
    draw.add({
      id: plot.id,
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        coordinates: [
          [
            [13.416708843044745, 52.5614769249415],
            [13.380877687507109, 52.56394508345741],
            [13.3508322992937, 52.54222052198426],
            [13.36260684773319, 52.52666110551999],
            [13.447160254426706, 52.51752046469531],
            [13.416708843044745, 52.5614769249415],
          ],
        ],
        type: 'Polygon',
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <GenericErrorMessage>
      <UIOverlay
        features={features}
        onDeletePlot={onDeletePlot}
        plotToEdit={plotToEdit}
        handlePlotToEdit={handlePlotToEdit}
        resetMapMode={() => {
          handleMapMode('simple_select');
        }}
      />
      <DrawControl
        draw={draw}
        features={features}
        plotToEdit={plotToEdit}
        displayControlsDefault={false}
        defaultMode={mapMode}
        onCreate={onDrawPlot}
        onUpdate={onDrawPlot}
        onDelete={onDeletePlot}
      />
    </GenericErrorMessage>
  );
};
```

Comment: The error i'm recieveing from Mapbox is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')